# Automapper. Map inside CreateMap

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have the following mappings:

```
CreateMap<Entity, EntityResponse>(); // #1

CreateMap<Source<Entity>, Dest<EntityResponse>>()
    .ConvertUsing(source =>
    {
        // here I need to use mapping from line 1#
        EntityResponse resp = <mapping>; 
        var tmp = new Source<Entity>(resp);
        return new Dest<EntityResponse>(tmp);
    });
```

Class `Dest<T>` contains constructor `Dest<T>(Source<T>)`

I need to use the first mapping (line #1) in the second one but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: But there is no need for that. See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Open-Generics.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `CreateMap<Source<Entity>, Dest<EntityResponse>>()`,

```
CreateMap<Entity, EntityResponse>(); is enough.
```